# Why "400 missing contact" response for REFER sip request?

Tags: jain-sip

i'am trying to create REFER request to forward calls, i have created Refer-To and Referred-By headers and for the contact Header it is as follos  `SipURI myURI = address.createSipURI(contactNew, realm);
                 Address contactAddress = addressFactory.createAddress(myURI);
                 contactAddress.setDisplayName(contactNew);
                 ContactHeader contactHeader = headerFactory.createContactHeader(contactAddress);`

(contactNew is the contact value and realm is my domain)
when i send the REFER request i got the response "400 missing contact" and the contact header doesn't figure in my request! i didn't find where is the problem!
Can anyone help me ? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't see you adding that contact header to the request that you are sending. Do you do this:

```
referRequest.addHeader(contactHeader);
```

You must do that before sending the request. Otherwise you just have an unused standalone contact header. If that's not the problem then you should attach debug logs.

Comment: Sorry i didn't put the hole code. Yes, i added the contact header to the request , and the problem persists! i didn't find where is the problem. 
PS: i used  the same instructions to  create contact header for invite request and it works!!! How can i fix it for REFER?

Comment: Well, I can't tell you anything without seeing the code or the logs. I can only tell you this works fine for me:

 public void sendRefer(String to) throws Exception, SipException {
  Request req = dialog.createRequest("REFER");
  req.addHeader(headerFactory.createHeader("Refer-To", "sip:"+to+"@"+realm));
  req.addHeader(headerFactory.createHeader("Referred-By", "sip:"+user+"@"+realm));
  dialog.sendRequest(provider.getNewClientTransaction(req));
 }

Comment: i call my application, i receive this msg:

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void refer(Request request, String referTo, String referredBy, String contactNew) throws Exception {

        try{
            AddressFactory address = SipFactory.getInstance().createAddressFactory();
            FromHeader fromheader = (FromHeader)request.getHeader(FromHeader.NAME);
            String tagfrom=fromheader.getTag();
           // System.out.println(((FromHeader)request.getHeader(FromHeader.NAME)).getAddress().toString());

            //from
            SipURI myRealmURI = addressFactory.createSipURI(username, realm);
            Address fromAddress = addressFactory.createAddress(myRealmURI);
            fromAddress.setDisplayName(username);
            FromHeader fromHeader = headerFactory.createFromHeader(fromAddress, new BigInteger(130, tag).toString(32));
            //to
    //ki nous a appelé!?????
            String appelant=((FromHeader)request.getHeader(FromHeader.NAME)).getAddress().toString();
            int index=appelant.indexOf("@");
            int index1=appelant.indexOf(":");
            SipURI myRealmURII = addressFactory.createSipURI(appelant.substring(index1+1, (index)), realm);
            Address toAddress = addressFactory.createAddress(myRealmURII);
            toAddress.setDisplayName(appelant.substring(index1+1, (index)));
            ToHeader toHeader = headerFactory.createToHeader(toAddress,tagfrom);
            //refer-to:à saisir
            String ref="sip:"+referTo + "@"+realm;
            ReferToHeader referto = headerFactory.createReferToHeader( 
                addressFactory.createAddress( ref )
            );
            //contactHeader

            //referred-by
            Header referredby = headerFactory.createHeader("Referred-By","sip:"+referredBy+"@"+realm);                

            URI requestURI =addressFactory.createURI("sip:sip.ooredoo.tn"+":"+distantPort);                
            List<ViaHeader> viaHeaders = new ArrayList<>();
            CallIdHeader callIdHeader = sipProvider.getNewCallId();
            long seq = 1;
            CSeqHeader cSeqHeader = headerFactory.createCSeqHeader(seq++, Request.REFER);
            int max=70;
              MaxForwardsHeader maxForwards = headerFactory.createMaxForwardsHeader(max);
            Request reques = messageFactory.createRequest(requestURI, Request.REFER, callIdHeader,
                 cSeqHeader, fromHeader, toHeader, viaHeaders, maxForwards);

            SipURI myURI = address.createSipURI(contactNew, realm);
            Address contactAddress = addressFactory.createAddress(myURI);
            contactAddress.setDisplayName(contactNew);
            ContactHeader contactHeader = headerFactory.createContactHeader(contactAddress);
            request.addHeader(contactHeader);
            reques.addHeader(referto);
            reques.addHeader(referredby);

            System.out.println(contactHeader.toString());

            ClientTransaction transaction = sipProvider.getNewClientTransaction(reques);
            transaction.sendRequest();

            System.out.println(reques.toString());  
            CallID callidres = (CallID)reques.getHeader(CallID.NAME);
           ((DefaultTableModel)jTable3.getModel()).addRow(new Object[]{new            date().date(),username,appelant.substring(index1+1, (index))    ,contactNew,password,localPort,distantPort,protocol,proxy,ipSRC,callidres.getValue(),"REGISTERED","REFER"});
     } catch (Throwable e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("Can't send REFER reply.");
     }        }
```

PS: this is the method of "refer"